# How to use a numpy array to generate array of meshes in blender?

Tags: python, numpy, blender, bpy

I would like to use blender to visualize a scatter plot animation with data from a large  2D array, such as

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
              [1, 2, 1],
              [4, 0, 1]]).
```

Here `a[i]` describes the position of the `i`-th mesh/object. I wish to create these objects in the blender scene. The following code does that with cubes, but is too slow when `a` contains thousands of vectors.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
              [1, 2, 1],
              [4, 0, 1]])
for pos_vec in a:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=pos_vec)
```

How can I do this without looping in python or make it as fast as possible?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your "3D" array is a more like point Cloud data.

And Blender can import `.ply` point cloud data

`bpy.ops.import_mesh.ply(filepath="PATH_TO_PLY.ply")`

And Before that you just need to convert your 3-D array to `.ply`, there are plenty of ways. Each below will work.

- Supposed you have your 3-D array in `numpy.array`. You can try [python2plyfile](https://github.com/dranjan/python-plyfile)
- matlab

```matlab
array3D =[1,0,0
          2,0,0
          3,0,0]
pc = pointCloud(array3D) 
pcwirte(pc, "PLY_FILE.ply")
```